# Remove an item when user deselect a flatlist item

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I know the title is not clear enough but I will try to explain more here.
I have a flatlist that I have to select multi Items and create a string value containing the item's id and item's price that I have to send to server.
this is my approach: (it work fine)

```
  selectItem = data => {
    let test = 130;
    if (data.Unites < test) {
      data.Etat = 0
      console.warn('points insufisants');
    } else {
      data.isSelect = !data.isSelect;
      data.selectedClass = data.isSelect ? StylesGift.validChek : StylesGift.inValidChek;
      const newItem = {
        idCadeau: data.idCadeau,
        Unites: data.Unites,
      };

      if (data.isSelect) {
        const index = this.state.paramsSend.indexOf([newItem]);

        this.setState({
          paramsSend: this.state.paramsSend.concat([newItem]),
        }, () => {
          let str = this.state.paramsSend.map(v => Object.values(v).join('_')).join(',')
          this.setState({
            params: str,
          });
        });
      }else if (data.isSelect === false) {
        const index = this.state.paramsSend.indexOf([newItem]);
        if (index > -1) {
          array.splice(index, 1);
          let str = this.state.paramsSend.map(v => Object.values(v).join('_')).join(',')
          this.setState({
            params: str,
          });
        }

   

        console.log('looog' + this.state.paramsSend);
      }
    }
    this.setState({changed: !this.state.changer})

  };
```

My probleme is whene I deselect an item I can't remove the item's id and price with this code:

```
    else if (data.isSelect === false) {
        const index = this.state.paramsSend.indexOf([newItem]); <-- =-1
        if (index > -1) {
        this.state.paramsSend.splice(index, 1);
let str=this.state.paramsSend.map(v=>Object.values(v).join('_')).join(',')
              this.setState({
                params: str,
              });
            }
            console.log('looog' + this.state.paramsSend);
          }
```

any suggestion please ? indexOf return -1
I don't know why

```
const index = this.state.paramsSend.indexOf([newItem]);
console.warn('index ' + index);
console.warn('from this ' +JSON.stringify(this.state.paramsSend));
console.warn('remove this ' + JSON.stringify(newItem));
```

newItem is already in paramsSend but it return -1 !
[image]

Comment: the `array.splice()` it's fine for removing items from an array, so where do you have an error? is `index === -1`?

Comment: it doesn't remove anything

Comment: Oh yes it gives me -1 when I log index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 issues:

1. don't call `indexOf` with an array, but just with the element you're looking for: `const index = this.state.paramsSend.indexOf(newItem);`
2. `indexOf(item)` called on an array of objects works only if `item` argument is an actual object in the array, not a copy. i.e. this won't work: `const index = this.state.paramsSend.indexOf({ idCadeau: 5, Unites: 180 });` even though an identical object exists in the array

So this should solve both issues:

```js
const index = this.state.paramsSend.findIndex(item => item.idCadeau === newItem.idCadeau)
if (index > -1) {
  // good!
}
```

Comment: it works better I had just to change item.id by item.idCadeau , thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't very clear, but try to use the filter function.

It push in a array all elements matching the condition

```
const newDataArray = data.filter(elem => elem.idCadeau !== newItem.idCadeau)
```

So here, you have a new array with all the elements wich are not the same than your newItem